# Adding Hyperlinks in a richtextbox that activate a method instead of a webpage

Tags: c#, textbox, hyperlink

Specifically, im looking for a way to add links to all the words in my (rich)textbox that start with #. so, if my richTextBox1.Text property equaled "This is an #example of what i want" i would want "#example" to be highlighted. and if its clicked, id want to add a context menu for right click, and just on left click id want it to trigger a void in my program, with the text that was clicked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at the following CodeProject article:

**Links with arbitrary text in a RichTextBox**
http://www.codeproject.com/KB/edit/RichTextBoxLinks.aspx

The code in this article will allow you to insert arbitrary text links into your `RichTextBox`.  When the text link is clicked, the [LinkClicked](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.linklabel.linkclicked.aspx) event will fire, and the [LinkLabelLinkClickedEventArgs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.linklabellinkclickedeventargs.aspx) will contain the text of the link you clicked.

Comment: Im using the LinkClicked event for actual links.. but im sure ill be able to work something out. thanks! ill take a look.